# http error 500 after trying to restore Magento 1.9 from backup

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a magento 1.9 website that I took a backup of the database and all files and uploaded them to a new server. However now when I go to the website it gives me a 500 error.

I reset all the file/folder permissions and also the directory ownership is the same as it is on the origional production website
Var/Log is writing no log files. So where else can I look to find the error?

Comment: Where would I find the apache server logs I looked in /var/log/apache2 and that directory is empty ?

Comment: Apache error log path is may be different by server provider, So you can check with server support for that.

Comment: have you checked if you have any file under var/report?

Answer (score 0):

500 server error only you can see inside your server's Apache or Nginx error log not from the magento var/log.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the permissions setting on the index.php file. The restore sets it to 666 and Cpanel considers that a security risk.  Change the setting to 644.